# Spring ViewResolver is mapping to an incorrect view

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am working through a simple application that I was following in an online tutorial (gontu series) to learn about Spring annotations.

I have a controller class called StudentAdmissionController that handles all calls from the spring-dispatcher-servlet.  The annotation is as follows.  I am just showing a snippet for readability.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("admissionForm");
    return model;
}
```

This launches a JSP called admissionForm.jsp that collects two fields.  This part works fine.  My `<form>` tag within the JSP looks like this.

```
<form action="/FirstSpringMVCProject/submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
```

I have an annotation in my controller to handle this submit that looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam("studentName") String     name, @RequestParam("studentHobby") String hobby) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("admissionSuccess");

    logger.info("Returning " + model.getViewName());
    model.addObject("msg", "Details submitted by you:: Name: " + name + ", Hobby: " + hobby);

    return model;

}
```

For some weird reason, when it comes back to the dispatcher servlet, it is trying to show a page called submitAdmissionForm.jsp (which is the name of the annotation).

I don't understand why it is doing this.  The annotation for the GET works fine because the annotation just happened to be the same name as the view (admissionForm).  I put in a logger statement and in debug, the view being supplied to the model appears to be the correct one (admissionSuccess) which I want to run a file called admissionSuccess.jsp.  But the viewResolver is trying to run a file called submitAdmissionForm.jsp (which does not exist) and just happens to be exactly what I have called my annotation.  That's not how it is supposed to work....

I must be doing something wrong...the example I was following on Youtube works fine...so What is going on with the view resolver in my dispatcher-servlet...please help.

My dispatcher servlet looks like this.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.studentadmissioncontroller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>


<bean id="viewResolver" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property> 
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>


</bean>
```

Comment: can please share you jsp location in WEB-INF and your web.xml file ..?

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)` does what you ask him to do : handle an `HttpRequest` with POST HTTP method, and set the mapping  to handle these request, here your `submitAdmissionForm.html` nothing more, nothing less.

If you want to display another view, then set the viewname accordingly in your `ModelAndView` with something like `model.setView("admissionSuccess");` and returns it. It will do that great ;)

Don't forget to check if any binding errors are set in your form before returning any success views :)

Edit: Looking deeper in your code, it looks ok. But usually I put the same handler name, and use different methods names like editStudent() coupled with editSubmitStudent() but they are pointing the same URL handler editStudent.do in my case, but you seems to prefer editStudent.html in your case ;)

OK : set action in your JSP form tag with `<c:url value="/admissionForm.html" var="admissionFormUrl">` and use it to submit your form accordingly `form action=${admissionFormUrl}` to your handler mapping. It will resolved that problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.  I figured out my problem.  Very silly.  I had imported the wrong library at the top of my class file.

This is the one I should have imported

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

I had accidentally selected this one instead

import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

That is why it was misbehaving...Once I changed it, it is working fine.

Regards,

Ajit